# Problems with com cross validation and pool on catboost

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation, catboost

I am using catboost `(version = catboost-0.10.4.1 enum34-1.1.6)` in a mac (Python 3.6.3 | Anaconda) and I got some problems with the module **cv** (with the cat_features parameter of the pool). Here is the exemple:

1) Using catboost in a single fit:

`from catboost import CatBoostClassifier, cv,`

`model = CatBoostClassifier(early_stopping_rounds=30,cat_features = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],iterations=2000,eval_metric='AUC',learning_rate=0.1,)`

`model.fit(X_train, y_train,eval_set=(X_test,y_test))`

Everything works just fine and I got my outputs!

2-) When I try to use basically the same thing with the cv module the problem appears:

```
cv_data = cv(pool=Pool(X_train, y_train,cat_features = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),params=model.get_params())
```

**Output :**

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CatboostError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-242-675cf317e148> in <module>()
----> 1 cv_data = cv(pool=Pool(X_train, y_train,cat_features=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]),params=model.get_params())

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/catboost/core.py in cv(pool, params, dtrain, iterations, num_boost_round, fold_count, nfold, inverted, partition_random_seed, seed, shuffle, logging_level, stratified, as_pandas, metric_period, verbose, verbose_eval, plot, early_stopping_rounds, save_snapshot, snapshot_file, snapshot_interval)
   2900 
   2901     with log_fixup(), plot_wrapper(plot, params):
-> 2902         return _cv(params, pool, fold_count, inverted, partition_random_seed, shuffle, stratified, as_pandas)
   2903 
   2904 

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._cv()

_catboost.pyx in _catboost._cv()

CatboostError: catboost/libs/options/plain_options_helper.cpp:272: Error: unknown option cat_features with value [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

The indexes are right for the categorical variables (and worked for a single fit).

I can't understand what is happening and couldn't find related content.
Can somebody help?

Comment: cv doesn't take cat_features as an option jet, so you need to pass cat_features to Pool constructor. Which is what you did. So to make your example work you need to remove cat_features from params map before passing it to params in cv. I've created an issue to fix this: https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/621